# filtrar todos los numeros que contengan 0 en un array

Tags: java, array

basicamente debo dividir los datos de un array A con los de un array B pero solo dividir los que no contengan un 0 como el 90,101,etc. llevo esto:

```
float div[];
div = new float[10];
for (int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){

div[i] = vec2[i] / vec1[i];
}
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
if((vec1[i] !=0 && vec1[i] != 10) || vec2[i] > 111){ 

//todo el if es una solucion parche
//el vec1 son numeros de 0-100 y el vec2 de 101 a 150
    
System.out.println("\n division: "+div[i]+" esta en la posicion "+i);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema? fijate si el numero contiene un cero o no ;)

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de ver los que tengan **0** podría ser:

```
string sNum = "";
bool tieneCero = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    sNum = arrelo[i].ToString(); 

    if(sNum.Contains("0"))
    {
        tieneCero = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Lo que haces aquí es recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo, y en la **variable** **sNum** guardas el elemento actual del arreglo, pero en vez de guardarlo como un número lo guardas como un **string**. Posteriormente usas el **método** **Contains** para ver si ese número tiene un **0**, de tener **0**, la **variable** **tieneCero** toma el valor de **true** y se sale del **ciclo for** con un **break**.

Aquí te mostré como saber si el número tiene un **0**, adapta este ejemplo a tu código y trata de hacer el resto del ejercicio tu mismo.

Comment: la idea me esta sirviendo pero no logro adaptarlo bien , me da error